# Image converter in Qt, colored image to black-white

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a simple program that converts colored images to black-white images.

So far I have made this.

```
void ObradaSlike::convert_picture_to_bw()
{
    QImage image;
    image.load(fileModel->fileInfo(listView->currentIndex()).absoluteFilePath());

    QSize sizeImage = image.size();
    int width = sizeImage.width(), height = sizeImage.height();

    QRgb color;
    int value;

    for (int f1=0; f1<width; f1++) {
        for (int f2=0; f2<height; f2++) {
            color = image.pixel(f1, f2);
            image.setPixel(f1, f2, QColor((qRed(color) + qGreen(color) + qBlue(color))/3).rgb());
        }
    }
    sceneGraphics->clear();
    sceneGraphics->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
}
```

I think the code should work, but there is a problem.

The problem with this code is that I always get blue-black images insted black-white images. Do you know how to fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Try this instead:

```
int gray = qGray(color);
image.setPixel(f1, f2, qRgb(gray, gray, gray));
```

Note that `qGray()` actually computes [luminosity](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/) using the formula `(r*11 + g*16 + b*5)/32`.

If you want to get a normal average like you are trying to do now:

```
int gray = (qRed(color) + qGreen(color) + qBlue(color))/3;
image.setPixel(f1, f2, qRgb(gray, gray, gray));
```